# jquery post data from loaded script

Tags: php, jquery

I want to post data from a loaded php script in my "index.php"
Here is what I mean:

```
// in my "index.php"

      $("body").load("index2.php")

// in my "index2.php"

      $.post("index3.php", { name : username })
```

"index3.php" does not receive the data sent even though the syntax is correct. I guess It's because "index2.php" is artificially loaded by jQuery and it doesn't receive data.

When I try to load "index3.php" I get the error ' undefined index "name"   '.
So what am I missing out? Thanks in advance.   :-)

Comment: what jquery version are you using?

Comment: I think that your ajax request is right, but the index3.php file could contains errors. To be sure that your request is right, you can check if your data is being sent to server trough your request (network panel)

Comment: Please use PostMan to test the request first https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en